# Search textfield in webpage +ios

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, uiwebview

Edited Question
I had read the webpage by using:-

```
NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
```

Now i want to search the UITextField into the webpage.

What should i do ?
So that i can find whether there is any UITextField is their in the webpage which is opened in UIWebView.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this by:

```
NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML parser can be used for HTML parsing so use NSURLConnection to read the webpage into an NSData object then parse it with the NSXMLParser using its initWithData property.

Comment: His answer is still valid for your query. In your case, you can just use a regular expression to get the textfield.